# Adding doubledata from text file to array (Java)

Tags: java, double

I am trying to figure out how to read data from a text file formatted as below:

1.0,8.0
4.0,3.0
6.0,0.0
3.0,5.0

and add the first element of each line in myNumbers1 and the second in myNumbers2 like so:

double[] myNumbers1 = {};
double[] myNumbers2 = {};

to get

double[] myNumbers1 = {1.0,4.0,6.0,3.0};
double[] myNumbers2 = {8.0,3.0,0.0,5.0};

if that makes sense? Thanks! :)

Comment: Is this csv format? Look for a csv reader library, read all lines and distribute the elements in your arrays. That said, questions here tend to do better if you can provide the code you've already tried and what problems you had with it. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way to achieve what you want.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("src/main/resources/file.txt"));

double[] first = new double[lines.size()];
double[] second = new double[lines.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
     String line = lines.get(i);
     String[] split = line.split(",");
     first[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
     second[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
}
```

Comment: Would this work the same as if I had just put in the data manually
i.e.
double[] myNumbers1 = {1.0,4.0,6.0,3.0};  
double[] myNumbers2 = {8.0,3.0,0.0,5.0};

Comment: @user18692484 what do you mean by "work the same"? You asked how to read numbers from a file and now you asking how it would work if you hardcode numbers in array creation. I don't know your goal, so I can't answer your question. You can always try and see if it's gonna work?